Flutterwave custom meta data not working with transfer api
I'm making a wallet to wallet transfer using the transfer api passing meta parameter and didn't get meta data pass  from the response. But if I pass a meta to bank transfer I get meta as response.
Can any one help with why is custom meta is not been passed with the response.
E.g "meta": {"quantity": "24", "goods_received_at": "24/02/21"}
I expect to get the meta data when making wallet to wallet transfer

Hello. Welcome to SO, your question is missing a lot of details about the actual issue, a context & code, a debugging details. Please, take a look at this meta post to get more help about how to post a good question

the payload is below:
{     //Transfer to a F4B Wallet      "account_bank": "flutterwave",     "account_number": "234000002538577",     "amount": 200,     "currency": "NGN",     "debit_currency": "NGN",     "reference": "YOUR_PAYMENT_REFERENCE24nu78yuu98",     "narration": "wallet transfer",     "debit_subaccount": "PSABFFE5634228544975",     "meta": {         "sender" : "john doe",         "quantity": "24"     } }
